# What can I do in one round?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, actions, action-economy

I'm still little confused about actions in Pathfinder. There are standard actions, move actions, full round actions, free actions, etc. I need to know which combinations of these actions I can use in one round. Could someone give me a summary and clarify it for me?

Comment: Thank you, you have just cleared up so much confusion at the table.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

According to [The ever useful d20PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Actions-In-Combat):

In a round of combat, you can do either :

- 1 [Full-round action](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Full-Round-Actions) OR
- 1 [Standard action](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Standard-Actions) plus 1 [Move action](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Move-Actions) (in any order) OR
- 2 Move actions (effectively trading your Standard action for a Move action)

Plus a combination of :

- 1 [Swift](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Swift-Actions) or [Immediate](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Immediate-Actions) Action AND
- Any number of [Free Actions](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Free-Actions) AND
- Any number of ["Not an Action" Actions](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/combat/#Not_an_Action)

### A few special cases

***The 5 ft. step***
**Provided you don't take any other action that actually involves using a move speed (walking/running/flying...) during the same round**, you can take a 5' step as a free action that does not provoke attacks of opportunity once per round.

***Spellcasting***
While most spells have a casting time of 1 Standard action, others can take a Swift action, a Full-round Action or more. For those spells that take longer to cast, you're effectively using up a Full-round action each round for the duration of the casting.
Also, be they Quickened spells or whatever, **you can never take more than 1 Swift action per round**.

Comment: Any references on "trading down"? Can I do 2 swift actions instead of 1 Std + 1 swift?

Comment: @gatesVP no, not supported.

Comment: I would allow "trading down" in cases where the ability normally takes a standard or move action, and the character has an ability that "improves" it to a swift action.  I know that there were definitely places in 3.5 where the limitation of 1 swift action a round was used as a balancing feature on special abilities; I'm not sure about PF but it wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: @starwed Oh! You meant that you'd allow players to trade *up* swift actions to Standard or Move actions, so long as the new action type is the appropriate action type of the action if it hadn't been altered by a character ability. I see! Yes, that takes care of the balance issue nicely. I'm sorry it took me so long to get your meaning. Thanks for being patient with me.

Comment: How strict is the 5-ft step special case? Say I take a 5-ft step. I still have my standard action. Can I still "trade" the standard action for a move action?

Comment: @hal9000 that should really be its own separate question I think. Anyway, the answer is yes. But you can't use that move action to move, because you already took the step (you can use it to draw an item or to open a door, for example).