# How are the Action Economies of Pathfinder 1e and D&D 3.5 Different?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, edition-comparison, action-economy

I’m going to be GMing a Pathfinder Adventure Path with PF1e rules, but with some D&D players (who are familiar with 3.5 and 5e rules). This’ll be their first foray into PF so I wanted to explain some (not all, at least not until we get to those parts anyway) mechanical differences between 3.5 and PF1e.

I came across [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/3183) outlining the differences between D&D 3.5e and PF1e, but it didn’t explain anything about differences in action economy. I found [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/16730) for the PF1e and this post about D&D action economy, but nothing really outlining how PF1e is different from D&D 3.5.

Can someone explain how PF 1e action economy differs from D&D 3.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Action economy is the same. 1 standard, 1 move, and 1 swift action per turn.

Pathfinder is nearly identical to 3.5e in regards to action economy, with the exception that swift actions are now core(and much more common), rather than found in a few side books.

The only thing that changes the action economy at all are *optional* rules published in *Pathfinder Unchained* (for reference [Revised Action Economy](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/unchained-rules/unchained-action-economy/) and [Removing Iterative Attacks.](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/unchained-rules/removing-iterative-attacks/)) and the optional [Hero Points](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/hero-points/) system from the *Advanced Players Guide*, which, among other options, allows spending a Hero Point to gain another action, in a manner similar to (and probably heavily based on) 3.5e Action Points.